# How does the view of an observer near an event horizon change as a function of the observer's position, velocity, and acceleration?

Tags: general-relativity, event-horizon

I see that this topic has been well covered from the perspective of a) a stationary observer dangling on the end of a rope and and b) an observer free-falling from infinity.  What I'm still unsure about are the roles of velocity vs. acceleration. Is it all about velocity?  Does an observer who is stationary near the horizon and only just starting to freefall see the same as a)?  Also, for an observer who is descending at close to escape velocity but then fires his/her retrorockets to cancel the acceleration and achieve constant velocity, does he/she still see the same as b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is what lies on your past light cone. The past light cone only depends on spacetime position, not velocity or higher derivatives.

What you see also depends on your velocity in the sense that it is "distorted" in different ways by Doppler shift and aberration. But given a (infinite-precision, omnidirectional) photograph of what someone at a particular location with a particular velocity sees, you can derive what someone at the same location with any other velocity will see just from that picture, without needing to know anything about the 4D spacetime it was originally derived from.

Acceleration doesn't affect what an idealized camera/eye sees.

> Does an observer who is stationary near the horizon and only just starting to freefall see the same as a)? Also, for an observer who is descending at close to escape velocity but then fires his/her retrorockets to cancel the acceleration and achieve constant velocity, does he/she still see the same as b)?

Yes to both questions, and also, if you ignore Doppler shift and aberration, all four of them see the same thing when they're at the same spacetime location even if they don't match their velocities.

Comment: That's a very good point: - that the photons intercepted by the observer should be a function only of position.  But it seems like the Doppler-shift (and aberration?) should be a function of position, velocity, and acceleration (position because of gravitational time-dilation, velocity from the conventional Doppler effect, and acceleration through the equivalence with gravity).

Comment: "the photons intercepted by the observer should be a function only of position".  On reflection, I don't think think that's quite correct.  The region covered by an observer's past light cone from a given position depends on the velocity of the observer. Isn't that the basis of special relativity?  So there are events that a moving observer will see that a stationary observer may not see.  So, for a given position, not only will there be red-shifts and aberrations that depend on velocity, but the field-of-view will be also be dependent on velocity.

Comment: @RogerWood No, the past light cone depends only on position. Maybe you're thinking of planes of simultaneity. It's true that they depend on velocity as well as position, but they also have no physical significance.

Comment: You are correct, of course.  "Planes of simultaneity" is an interesting concept. This means that observers at the same position but different velocities will see distorted versions of the same scene but may deduce that the same events they both see actually occured in a different time sequence.  But there's a situation that still troubles me ...

Comment: As I understand it, two astronauts, A & B, free-falling closely-spaced one-after-the-other into a very large black hole may still be able to communicate normally even though they mutually agree that one is inside the event horizon and one is outside. However, if the second astronaut, B, is suddenly arrested just before the event horizon, then he/she will presumably see A hovering just above the event horizon.  I guess the resolution is that even though A may be inside the event horizon by B's reckoning, the image in free-fall B sees of A is actually of A just before the event horizon.